Intersection of Frobenius subalgebra objects
$\require{AMScd}$Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a tensor category and let $M$ be a Frobenius algebra object in $\mathcal{C}$. A Frobenius subalgebra object of $M$ is a Frobenius algebra object $X$ equipped with a monomorphism $i_X: X \to M$, which is compatible with the algebra and unit structures (although not necessarily with the coalgebra and counit structures, otherwise $i_X$ would be an isomorphism).
Following [Fr64, $\S$1.5], $(X, i_X)$ is a subobject of $M$ (more precisely, a representative of an equivalence class), and these subobjects form a poset. The intersection $A \cap B$ of two subobjects $A$ and $B$ is defined in [Fr64, $\S$2.1] as the greatest lower bound, and it is proven to be the pullback as displayed in the following diagram:
$$
\begin{CD}
A \cap B @>j_A>> A \\
@VVj_BV @VVi_AV \\
B @>i_B>> M
\end{CD}
$$
Assume that $A$ and $B$ are Frobenius subalgebra objects of the Frobenius algebra object $M$.
Question: Is it true that $A \cap B$ is also a Frobenius subalgebra object of $M$?
A Frobenius algebra object is self-dual, and to prove that $A \cap B$ is a Frobenius subalgebra object of $M$, I first need to prove that it is self-dual. In the more general case where $A$, $B$, and $M$ are just assumed to be self-dual, then $A \cap B$ is self-dual in the semisimple case but does not necessarily remain so otherwise. For counterexamples, see the answers to this post.
If the above question has a negative answer, I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to define such an intersection to yield a positive answer.

Reference:
[Fr64] Freyd, Peter. Abelian Categories: An Introduction to the Theory of Functors. Harper's Series in Modern Mathematics. Harper & Row, Publishers, New York, 1964. xi+164 pp.

What is definitely not true is that if you have a finite dimensional Frobenius algebra then the intersection of two Frobenius subalgebras is a Frobenius subalgebra. Even in the commutative case.

@DaveBenson Could the counterexamples you have in mind be realized as Frobenius algebra objects in a semisimple tensor category over $\mathbb{C}$?

Well, it's a finite dimensional commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Is that good enough for you? The smallest example is five dimensional. Woulld you like me to write out the details?

@DaveBenson Yes, please.

Here is the connected version: https://mathoverflow.net/q/478418/34538

Let $k$ be any field. Consider the commutative $k$-algebra $k[x,y,z]/(x^2,y^2,xz,yz,xy-z^2)$. This is a five dimensional algebra with basis $1$, $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$ where $u=xy=z^2$. It is clearly a Gorenstein ring, so it is a finite dimensional Frobenius algebra. Let $A$ be the subalgebra generated by $x$ and $y$, so that it has basis $1$, $x$, $y$ and $u$; and let $B$ be the subalgebra generated by $x$ and $y+z$, so that it has basis $1$, $x$, $y+z$, $u$. These are both Frobenius subalgebras. But their intersection has basis $1$, $x$ and $u$, with $x^2=u^2=xu=0$; this is not Frobenius because the socle is two dimensional.

The point here is that you can have a finite dimensional vector space with a non-degenerate quadratic form, and two non-degenerate subspaces whose intersection is degenerate.

Let me propose some possible additional assumptions. Please let me know if you find them relevant.
Suggestion 1: Assume that $i_A^* \circ i_A = \mathrm{id}_A$ and $i_B^* \circ i_B = \mathrm{id}_B$.
Suggestion 2: If the notations are coherent, Frobenius algebras are precisely the Frobenius algebra objects in the tensor category $\mathrm{Vec}$. Thus, assuming the Frobenius algebra to be "connected" (i.e., $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(1, M)$ is one-dimensional) allows us to avoid $\mathrm{Vec}$.
Would these additional assumptions be relevant in addressing the problem?

What is $i^*_A$?

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism in a rigid monoidal category. Then $f^: Y^ \to X^*$ is the dual morphism.

There seem to be several ways to interpret this for a Frobenius algebra. You're given a map $M \otimes M \to k$, which by adjunction gives a left and a right map $M \to M^$. So $i^_A\circ i_A$ really means $A \to M \to M^* \to A^* \to A$ using some choices for these maps?
Even so, since my example is not just Frobenius but also symmetric, the map $M \otimes M \to k$ is symmetric so these choices agree. Then I think it just amounts to saying that the symmetric bilinear form on $A$ is the restriction of that on $M$. In my example this seems to already hold.

Yes. I just posted the connected version: https://mathoverflow.net/q/478418/34538

I have realized that my proof for the semisimple case necessitates an assumption stronger than symmetric. Specifically, I need the counit composed with the multiplication to be equal to the evaluation map ($\epsilon \circ m = ev_M$), and the comultiplication composed with the unit to be equal to the coevaluation map ($\delta \circ e = coev_M$). What does this stronger assumption translate to in the context of a (usual) Frobenius algebra (in ${\rm Vec}$)? Does your example meet this stronger assumption?

I have no idea what you mean by the counit and the comultiplication. That isn't part of the structure of a Frobenius algebra.

A Frobenius algebra object in a monoidal category is both an algebra and a coalgebra object that satisfies the Frobenius condition. If the notation is consistent, a Frobenius algebra should be a Frobenius algebra object in the category ${\rm Vec}$. Therefore, a Frobenius algebra should inherently possess a coalgebra structure.

Then you should be able to express your question in terms of the usual axioms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra

Could you provide your reference for the claim that a Gorenstein ring is a Frobenius algebra? The last link you cited indicates that a zero-dimensional Gorenstein ring (under additional assumptions) is a Frobenius algebra. However, the example you mentioned is five-dimensional. Could you clarify this discrepancy?

You're confused about the term "zero-dimensional". It refers to the Krull dimension, not the dimension as an algebra.

Does the poset of Frobenius subalgebras form a lattice? Based on your counterexample, it appears that the meet, if it exists, is not always determined by the intersection.

Here is a dedicated mathoverflow post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/481529/34538
